# sql case condition as SELECT from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case

I have a working procedure with case conditions. It gets triggered on every INSERT and checks for specific values in one column then updates another column. The entire SP has between 20-30 CASE conditions.
I'm moving from MySQL to PostgreSQL and was wondering if it is possible to automate it and have SELECT inside CASE? (see code below)

```
SELECT col1,col2 FORM myCASEtbl
ABC | 1
DEF | 2
123 | 3
```

---

FROM THIS:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET columnName = CASE
WHEN OtherColumn LIKE '%ABC%' THEN columnName = 1
WHEN OtherColumn LIKE '%DEF%' THEN columnName = 2
WHEN OtherColumn LIKE '%123%' THEN columnName = 4
...
ELSE columnName
END
WHERE columnName IS NULL;
```

---

TO THIS:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET columnName = CASE
SELECT 'WHEN OtherColumn LIKE ' + col1 + ' THEN columnName = ' + col2 FROM myCASEtbl
ELSE columnName
END 
WHERE columnName IS NULL
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET columnName = (SELECT ct.col2
                      FROM myCaseTable ct
                      WHERE mytable.OtherColumn like '%' || ct.col || '%'
                      LIMIT 1
                     )
    WHERE columnName IS NULL;
```

The `LIMIT` is a convenient way to guarantee that the subquery returns one row.

Comment: Why would I want to limit to 1? I want to list all possible cases

Comment: I think it's because you cannot assign a set (2 or more rows) to a column.

Comment: Ok, I see. So this would produce as many lines of CASE as before, therefore not what I was looking for...

Comment: @michal . . . I don't get your comment at all.  This would appear to do exactly what you want.  It doesn't "produce lines of `CASE`" (whatever that might mean).  It just returns the first matching value.

Comment: @gordon linoff, oh i see, I will test it tonight, and will update here, thanks